# Slide down similar to google image result

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-image-search

I'm trying to make something similar to the slide down functionality that Google uses in their images search results.

I've got something somewhat working within this jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ultraloveninja/X7rmK/

Using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.slider').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.internal').slideUp('normal');
        if ($(this).next().is(':hidden') === true) {
            $(this).addClass('on');
            $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
        }
    });
    $('.internal').hide();
});
```

But I'm not sure how to get it so the content that pertains to the image is underneath it.

I did find this link:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview/

But it's causing some issues when integrating it with isotope. So, I'm trying to roll my own and see if I can achieve something similar that will work when filtering with isotope.

Not too sure if I need to set something different within the CSS or if I need to make JS command it differently.

Comment: its too late to ask..but did you get a solution to this? even i am stuck at the same point with the positioning and floats clashing with each other! Any help or heads up will be awesome !

Comment: @Ajasra - I never really went back to this, but after looking at it, you'd probably want to do what Pervara suggested and keep all of the content within one specific div instead of having it separate. That way you can keep all of the positioning the same.

Comment: thanks UVninja for getting back. but the solution of Pevara works with the jsfiddle, but not with the actual problem, because, you are at a war of positions between isotope and the codrops plugin. Well i am trying to write it out myself..lets see what happens. will update for newer readers if i have a concrete solution to this.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just put your content inside the slider, after the image. They belong together, so it makes sense to group them. It would also make your problem (and js) a lot easier. Have a look at this:
http://jsfiddle.net/Pevara/X7rmK/2/

The html does now look like this:

```
<div class="slider">
    <img src="..." />
    <div class="internal">Content here</div>
</div>
```

And the js became a lot shorter:

```
$('.slider').click(function () {
    $(this).find('.internal').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But what I am trying to acheive visually is something similar to this: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/

The only problem is that it's conflicting with isotope for some reason.